# How do I change ogg:image only for homepage in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, meta-tags

for almost 2 days looking for information, but I can not find how to change this og tag only for index page (frontpage) of Magento. Do you have ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try with an if statement in your head like :

```
if(Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()) {
  // Insert og:image meta
}
```

or with the page identifier like :

```
if(
Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home' &&
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms'
) :  {
  // Insert og:image meta
}
```

**EDIT :**
To double check, I just tried in one of my sites to add
to app/design/frontend/default/my_theme/template/page/html/head.phtml :

```
<?php if(Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()) { ?>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl() ?>media/og-image.jpg" />
<?php }; ?>
```

And it works fine.

Comment: Hello @David, I try your suggestions, but they not working. Are you having other ideas on that?

Comment: Please check edit, I just tested it out.